# How to let python function pass more variables than what's accepted in the definition?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very generic function call that looks like

```
result = getattr(class_name, func_name)(result)
```

This function call updates `result`. This function call is very generic such that it can invoke many functions from different classes. Currently, all these functions only take one argument `result`. However, it doesn't scale to the cases that some functions need to pass more than just `result` but more arguments (say, `args`).

Is there a way in Python (2.7) that allows this generic function call to pass `args` but still invoke the functions that don't have the extra arguments? If not, what would be a better approach to solve this problem?

EDIT: I cannot change the existing function definitions, including those that only take only the argument `result`. I can only change this line:

```
result = getattr(class_name, func_name)(result)
```

Comment: def myfunc(*args) #passes list of arguments **args passes dictionary of all the supplied arguments. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3394835/args-and-kwargs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `*` within the function call. This will pass `result` as multiple arguments. Lets say you have two functions:

```
class YourClass:
   def my_first_def(one_arg):
      return (1, 2)

   def my_second_def(one_arg, second_arg):
      return (1, 2, 3)


if not instanceof(result, tuple):
  result = (result,)

result = getattr(YourClass, 'my_first_def')(*result)
result = getattr(YourClass, 'my_second_def')(*result)
```

Do note that `result` must be a `tuple`

Comment: It looks like a good solution, the only thing that doesn't fit into my project is that `my_first_def` and `my_second_def` return `result` only unfortunately. Any way around that?

Comment: You could add a check if the result is tuple. For instance: `if not instanceof(result, tuple): result = (result, )`

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for this is that when we want to provide a common function name such as this, that it is the responsibility of each class to implement its local definition of that function.  This is why you see, for example, a method **__init__** in many different classes.  The system standardizes the name, placing the requirement on the classes.

The other common way is borrowed from **C**: you pass a list of arguments, the canonical *args solution.  This allows one generic, flexible function to interpret the arglist as appropriate.